# How can i Calculate distance between two points Unity 3D?

Tags: c#-3.0, unity-game-engine

I need to calculate and display from my car to the ending point in using c# scripting (The problem here is, in some mission destination changes at run time)? Need Some Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html), like this:

```
Vector3.Distance(other.position, transform.position);
```

with the parameters being of type Vector3.

Answer (score 0):

use it:  Vector3.Distance(Vector3 point1,Vector3 point2) 
And you do math.abs it is Module of

Answer (score 0):

You can  also compare with Square Magnitude value.Here is one Example...

```
public Transform enemy;
public float minimumGap = 4.0F;

void Update() {

    if(enemy){

      Vector3 Gap = enemy.position - transform.position;
      float distanceGap = Gap.sqrMagnitude;

      if(distanceGap < minimumGap * minimumGap){

       // Do Something
   }
 }
 }
```